# WordPress (TinyMCE) not removing script tags

Tags: tinymce

We have an installation of WordPress (3.9) where TinyMCE is *not* removing script tags (in posts etc). This isn't correct, I believe?!

I think a developer that worked on the project possibly changed something when trying to sort something out, but I can't see where at the moment - what are the obvious places to look?

Thanks,

Toby

**Update**: This seems to happen on a fresh WP3.9 install. In the text tab of the post editor I can enter script tags, which persist *unless* I switch to the visual editor and save. I don't think that this is correct, I think that WP is supposed to strip script tags out...or did I miss something?

Comment: Which user roles experience this issue?

Comment: I'm seeing it logged in as an Administrator, haven't checked others.

Comment: I don't have the time to chase this down to verify it but the administrator should have "unfiltered html" capability. Try with another role.

Comment: editor seems to be able to do it too - I just did a fresh install of WP3.9, created a new post containing an alert between two script tags and the alert works...I also pulled in a js file...this can't be right can it?!

Comment: Are there any plugins on the site that may be modifying the editor's behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it was my oversight - and [s_ha_dum](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/21376/s-ha-dum) was almost spot on - I was kindly directed to this:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Security_FAQ#Why_are_some_users_allowed_to_post_unfiltered_HTML.3F

which explains the situation perfectly.

---

*In case this is of any use to anyone*

I have fixed it for the site I'm working on using the wp_insert_post_data filter, like this:

```
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data' , 'filter_post_data' , '99', 2 );

function filter_post_data( $data , $postarr ) {
    $data = wp_kses_post( $data );
    return $data;
}
```

I am hoping I've got something wrong here, this seems very...wrong?!